# Binary de-serialization - how to find, what type of serialization is it?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

I have a .dat file generated by a program. The program owner is not against parsing and editing this file, but he will not give anyone answers.

The file mostly consists of variables that are defined in this way:

In most cases:

```
(4 bytes - length of the var name)(var name)(4 bytes of some internal var type)(4 bytes - possibly are elements count)(X bytes of var value)
```

Rarely:

```
(4 bytes - length of the var name)(var name)(1 zero byte)(4 bytes of some internal var type)
```

So, for example:

```
([4 0 0 0][name])[11 0 0 0][1 0 0 0]([9 0 0 0][Alexander])
```

and

```
([8 0 0 0][names])[6 0 0 0](length [3 0 0 0])([4 0 0 0][John])([4 0 0 0][Anne])([7 0 0 0][SomeGuy])
```

I tried to look at boost binary serialization but it doesn't add variable names in the file and I think uses 8 bytes, not 4.

Comment: You need to have the stencil or layout of a binary data file in order to figure it out.  You have no idea how many bytes per unit (such as `uint8_t` or `uint32_t`).  Also, for multibyte quantities, you will need to know if the data is Little Endian or Big Endian ordering.

Comment: Try asking on the [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: Thomas, it's Macintosh ANSI (Notepad++). I'm sure that it's 4 bytes per unit. I figured out that length of the array is represented by 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic way to determine "what type of serialization" it is. The author of the format has made design decisions and arrived at a final format. It could be literally anything. You can make educated guesses ("reverse engineering") but the only way to know for sure is to obtain a specification from the author. Although you claim that he doesn't mind people manipulating files stored in this format, his refusal to provide said specification makes me wonder whether this is really true and, ultimately, means you may have to stick with guesswork.

Comment: It's .dat files for the game called Avorion. I already posted some utilities on the official forum that change this files. I got downloads and no ban or words like "don't do this again please".

Comment: @user64675 not getting shut down on the forum doesn't mean approval. It could mean you didn't generate enough attention to your actions, or it could indeed mean it is ok. You need to check the licensing under which the product is released.

Answer (score 0):

To add the the answer of [BoundaryImposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479708/2805305) there is no deserialization framework (that I know of) that can deal with "any" format. The format must be known and implemented by the library. So you need to do implement it yourself.